# jQuery scroll to top and scroll to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a position:fixed scroll-to-top button and another button that scrolls down the page section by section. I have seen a similar code that is working with IDs, but I would like to use the classes of the sections and .next() .closest() to get this done. Is this possible with jQuery?
The scroll to top and scroll to the second section work, but I cannot get past the second section with .next() and .closest()

This is my html:

```
<body>
<a href="#0" class="cd-top">Top</a>
<a href="#2" class="cd-next">next</a>
<div class="section">
    <section class="x_section">   1</section>
    <section class="x_section">   2</section>
    <section class="x_section">   3</section>
    <section class="x_section">   4</section> 
</div>
</body>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $next = $('.cd-next'), 
    $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');
    //smooth scroll to top
    $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0   }, 700 );
    });

  $next.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (typeof advance == 'undefined') {
          var fuller = $('section').closest('.x_section').next(),
              section = $('.x_section').closest('.x_section').next(),
              top0 = section.scrollTop(),
              advance = fuller.offset().top;
        }
        else { var advance = advance + fuller.offset().top; }
        $('html,body').animate({    scrollTop: top0 + 408 }, 700);
  }) ;
});
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pnemeth/uLrjdm7e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different approach than you are using, however it seems to get the job done.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // declare section count, set to 0
    var count = 0,
    sections = $(".x_section"),
    $next = $(".cd-next"),
    $top = $(".cd-top");

  $next.on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
// increment section count
count++;

$("html, body").animate({
        // scroll to section count
        scrollTop: $(sections.get(count)).offset().top
    });
  });
  
  $top.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // reset section count to 0
      count = 0;
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sections.get(0)).offset().top
    });
  });
});
```

Update: This solution technically fulfills your requirements of using .closest() and .next(), but uses a position marker which is appended to the next section div after each button click. When the user clicks the button to go back to top, the marker is appended to the first section div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $next = $(".cd-next"),
    $top = $(".cd-top");

  $next.on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
// get section closest to marker
var section = $('#marker').closest('.x_section'),
// get next section
nextSection = section.next();
// remove marker
section.find($('#marker')).remove();
// append new marker to next section
$(section.next()).append('<div id="marker"></div>');

$("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(nextSection).offset().top
    });
  });
  
  $top.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // append marker to first section
      $(document).find($('#marker')).appendTo($('.x_section').get(0));
      
      $("html, body").animate({
          // scroll to first section
        scrollTop: $($('.x_section').get(0)).offset().top
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I did not realize .next and .closest were pertinent to your design. I apologize.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the .closest() method finds the closest element in the DOM tree, not in the window view. I'm thinking the only way to get around this without using 'id tags' would be to write a function to calculate the window position in relation to each element of class "x_position", incrementing the element you are comparing to the window position every time you reach an element with class "x_position". It would be much easier, and use less code to go the 'id tag' route.

Comment: Hi Inkdot! Thanks for the solution! You are right, I started this in a more complicated way than it should be done. Your #1 solution works fine. #2 also includes next() and closest() what I believed was a good idea in the beginning, but now I am in favor of your first solution.